# Add columns to Power Query from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, powerquery

I'm using Kohera's Power Pivot Formula to get Google Analytics data in Power Query:
let

```
analytics = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?access_token=",
addAccessToken = analytics &
  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TblToken"]}[Content]{0}[Access Token],
addViewId = addAccessToken & "&ids=ga:33784873", 
addStartDate = addViewId & "&start-date=2014-10-01",
addEndDate = addStartDate & "&end-date=2014-12-31", 
addDimensions = addEndDate & "&dimensions=ga:operatingSystem", 
url = addDimensions & "&metrics=ga:sessions",
GaJson = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url)),
GetRows = GaJson[rows], 
TableFromList = Table.FromList(GetRows, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), 
  null, null, ExtraValues.Error), 
ColOS = Table.AddColumn(TableFromList, "OS", each [Column1]{0}),
ColCount = Table.AddColumn(ColOS, "Count", each [Column1]{1}),
RemoveFirstColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(ColCount,{"Column1"}) in RemoveFirstColumn
```

However, how do I add more columns? For example, if I wanted to do a query for ga:hostname,ga:country,ga:browser, how would I get this in M code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figured it out. To explain for others:

```
    TableFromList = Table.FromList(GetRows, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
ColHostname = Table.AddColumn(TableFromList, "Hostname", each [Column1]{0}),
ColCountry = Table.AddColumn(ColHostname, "Country", each [Column1]{1}),
ColBrowser = Table.AddColumn(ColCountry, "Browser", each [Column1]{2}),
ColCount = Table.AddColumn(ColBrowser, "Count", each [Column1]{3}),
RemoveFirstColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(ColCount,{"Column1"})
```